# InterlockedAdd on R32_Sint with negative number

Tags: directx-11, hlsl

I am writing to an `RWBuffer<int>` using `InterlockedAdd` - originally I had an `RWBuffer<uint>` but I needed my values to go negative sometimes.

I find that using `InterlockedAdd` passing a negative number doesn't update the underlying int buffer - I tested this by using abs() on the value being passed in, and it worked.

I realize using an Add method to add a negative number might seem like "doh ! what did you expect" but there isnt an `InterlockedSubtract()` so ...

Is this a known issue that I just haven't managed to find the docs for, or would you normally expect `InterlockedAdd(-1)` to subtract 1 from an `RWBuffer<int>` like I did ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how atomics are handled with typed buffers, but they definitely work with structured buffers.

In your case since typed buffer is R32 it would perfectly map to a int structured buffer.

Syntax would be :

```
RWStructuredBuffer<int> OutputBuffer : register(u0);
```

Then interlocked operation would be like (if you want to apply it on the 2nd element for example):

```
uint idx = 1;
uint current_value;
InterlockedAdd(OutputBuffer[idx],-1,current_value);
```

Buffer creation is slightly different, but nothing too complicated as a change (need to set the structured flag and also set element stride, which is 4 in that case).

Comment: Happy to mark as the answer, but not sure _why_ swapping RWBuffer<int> for RWStructuredBuffer<int> should make any difference.

Comment: RWBuffer supports hardware compression/decompression (so for example RWBuffer<int> can be a byte/short or int internally). So that's likely to not be so much atomic friendly.

Comment: thanks for the answer.